# Canvas.toDataURL() not working in IE having SVG content in Canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, canvas, svg

I have svg content and I want to draw this svg on canvas.Then I want dataURL of canvas but `IE` gives error of `SecurityError`.I have spent whole day but i didn't get right thing.Below is code that I have done so far.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.setAttribute("height", 500);
canvas.setAttribute("width", 500);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var DOMURL = self.URL || self.webkitURL || self;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], { type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8" });
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var image = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 
 };

img.onerror = function () {
 };

img.src = url;
```

On above code everything works fine in mozilla and chrome but IE gives an error on `canvas.toDataURL`. How can I fix this?? Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the problem is that your SVG itself is a data URI; data URI's are treated in some situations as if they were cross-origin files.  (In general, you can draw cross-origin images to canvas, but then the canvas becomes "tainted" and you can't read the data back or convert it to a data URI.)  Since you're creating the SVG code yourself, there's no security risk, but it depends on how they have implemented the data URI scheme.

Comment: @AmeliaBR Actually I am using `Highcharts`-third party chart tool and I just grab svg code as string from it and draw it on canvas using Blob as per above code , it works well in all browser except `IE`. so how can I overcome on this specially on IE..thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue using [Canvg.js](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/)